# How can I create a folder via Oracle form builder?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to know how I can create a folder via Oracle form Builder?
Is it possible?

I mean I want to create a folder dynamically and after that open it using Internet Explorer to customer that customer easily copy his files.

I am using oracle 6i.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Forms 6i running in client/server you could use the HOST command like this:

```
HOST('md c:\somefolder\newfolder');
```

In later web-based versions of Forms you would use CLIENT_HOST instead of HOST.

Comment: Thanks for yr answer,How about in 10g version?this work don't work :(

Comment: In 10G you would use CLIENT_HOST, which requires you to install the Webutil components.  I thought you said you were using 6i though?