# what's ur idea about this two way for creat a folder in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

According to my last question about how to create folder [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964252/create-a-folder) I find some codes that s.b before write it!
looking :
(sorry for limitation i cant put codes here)
they try to Create a bat file,by oracle

```
outfile text_IO,file_type
then they write these statement!
body_of_file = 'Net use x: \\address'
body_of_file += 'md' || filename
body_of_file += 'start '|| file name
```

then open bat file and write inside it!

then they call it by HOST!!!!
like:

```
Host('cmd /c \\address\.x.bat host_folder'|| sysdate);
```

but they can easily and directly by calling HOST!
and also I dont know why they code just can in oracle 6i!!!! we use 2 oracle 6i and 10g.

please would you help me :
1- why this code dont work in 10g?
2- which way is better?create a batch file and create folder or use HOST for run each command?(in my Idea both is same,How about u?)

Answer (score 4):

Oracle 6 was client server architecture. The 'Forms' code ran on the end user's PC and connected directly to the database. There were advantages in this (especially in interfacing to hardware on the client PC) but disadvantages too (eg distributing code changes to the client PC, security).

Oracle 10g is three tier architecture. The end user uses a browser to connect to an app server. The Forms code is running on the application server. The application server connects to the database.

There is still some processing on the client end, and with the addition of the [WebUtil](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/forms/htdocs/webutil/simplifiedWebUtil.html) layer, the Forms code is permitted to perform some [functionality](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/forms/htdocs/webutil/web_util.pdf) on the client box.

I'd write each command individually as it will be easier to handle errors (and there will be errors as you jump between different versions of Windows).